# sencha touch - date format

Tags: date, sencha-touch

I am getting the date from my store...

while display it, its like this..

```
Fri Aug 12 2011 08:56:18 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

but i want to display like

```
12 Aug 2011
```

In my store i kept as the type as date.

```
Ext.regModel('allVisit', {
            fields: [
                { name: 'visitDate', type: 'date'},
                { name: 'visitId', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'visitDetailId', type: 'string'},
            ]
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to specify the format in your output template e.g:

```
<div class="Dates">
    Test Date:
    {TestDate:date('l, F d, Y g:i:s A')} <br />
    {TestDate:date('d/m/Y H:i')}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use dateFormat (**dateFormat: 'g:i a'**) in your model :

```
Ext.regModel('allVisit', {
        fields: [
            { name: 'visitDate', type: 'date' dateFormat: 'g:i a' },
            { name: 'visitId', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'visitDetailId', type: 'string'},
        ]
    });
```

You can get help from [this doc](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#%21/api/Date%22)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code where you are trying to display the Date?
You'll most likely have to provide the format you want there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the date patterns in the beginning of the main javascript file such as

```
Date.patterns = {
    ISO8601Long : "Y-m-d H:i:s",
    ISO8601Short : "Y-m-d",
    ShortDate : "n/j/Y",
    LongDate : "l, F d, Y",
    FullDateTime : "l, F d, Y g:i:s A",
    MonthDay : "F d",
    ShortTime : "g:i A",
    LongTime : "g:i:s A",
    SortableDateTime : "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s",
    UniversalSortableDateTime : "Y-m-d H:i:sO",
    YearMonth : "F, Y"
};
```

Then you can apply these patterns according to your need as follows

Eg:

```
yourDate.format(Date.patterns.ISO8601Short);
yourDate.format(Date.patterns.ShortTime);
yourDate.format(Date.patterns.SortableDateTime);
```

Hope it will help....

Comment: Use date Format ShortTime for your need. @Shakthi